# Doctrine2 / Symfony2 --> sort result using finders

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Using Doctrine2 and Symfony2, how do we get directly sorted the result of a query?

You know that Symfony has this funny way to get data:

```
$array_objects = $repository->findAllByCriteria($criteria);
```

This would result on an array with all the objects fitting that $criteria.

But what if I want to get the results directly sorted by some $sorting_criteria?

Isn't there anything like:

```
$sorted_array_objects = $repository->findAllByCriteria($criteria)->sort($sorting_criteria);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it.

Just use QueryBuilder.

```
$arr_products = $pack_repo->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->where('p.active = true')
    ->orderBy('p.rating', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```